# Proftpd in application selection loop

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ftp, proftpd

I've installed a proftpd server locally for a project, and everything seems to work alright, i can access it via filezilla or the terminal.

The problem comes when I try to acces the ftp server through the web browser (firefox in this case), when I type the ftp ip address e.g. ftp://192.168.132.101, i get a prompt to select the application in which I want to open the link in, If I select firefox in the list, it opens another window with the ftp link, but with the same application selection prompt. If I select chrome as the application to open the link, the same thing happens.

I've tried this in windows installing a bridge adapter in my vm and I have the same problem. Is there any configuration I need to tweak to fix this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem comes when I try to acces the ftp server through the web browser (firefox in this case), when I type the ftp ip address e.g. ftp://192.168.132.101, i get a prompt to select the application in which I want to open the link in, If I select firefox in the list, it opens another window with the ftp link, but with the same application selection prompt. If I select chrome as the application to open the link, the same thing happens.

This is normal; that's because both Firefox and Chrome no longer support FTP access. (They both removed FTP support last month.)

Now when you try to open an FTP URL in Firefox, it'll always have to be opened using an external application (such as FileZilla, personally I'd prefer WinSCP). The browsers themselves shouldn't even appear in the list.

- [Intent to unship: FTP protocol implementation](https://groups.google.com/g/mozilla.dev.platform/c/FqCZUT9ay_o/m/jt4DLRDjAwAJ)

Comment: Oh, I see.. thanks for the info!

Comment: Browsers won't open FTP URL is any FTP application you might have installed. The application has to register to handle the `ftp://` URL in the OS. I do not think that FileZilla does that (*[my]* WinSCP does).

Comment: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/88.0/releasenotes/